# Covert an array to an active record relation in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following where clause...

```
User.where(location_id: params[:user_place_id]).map(&:open_session)
```

I would like to convert this to an Active Record relation so I can call order and pagination on it.

Looks like I want to .arr, but I'm not sure how to call that in this case.

## Edit

Here is the relation in the User model:

```
  has_many :open_sessions, :class_name => "Session", :foreign_key => "assignee_id", :conditions => "status_state = #{Session::STATUS_SUBMITTED}"
```

Comment: What is `open_session` with this information answer the question will be much easier. Otherwise you get people that are guessing at structure and pulling things out of thin air.

Comment: in that case look at @LeonidShevtsov's answer the first one should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, because an 'ActiveRecord relation' is in fact an abstraction over an SQL query. However, if can replicate the same logic as an ActiveRecord query, then you'll get the relation you want:

`Session.where(status_state: Session::STATUS_SUBMITTED).joins(:user).where(users: {location_id: params[:user_place_id]})`

and you can clean it up further with scopes.

Comment: Nice guess on what `open_session` was I think your first answer should work perfectly in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `:open_session` is meant to subselect your collection, you should make `:open_session` a scope and call it directly on the `where`:

```
User.where(location_id: params[:user_place_id]).open_session
```

This will return you an `AR::Relation` that you can then paginate/order.

If you post the code for `open_session` we can help clean this up.